# IDL Transforming a PNG Given Input Image and Location of Output Pixels

Tags: image-processing, transformation, idl-programming-language

I'm using IDL to take an image of the outside surface of a cylinder and flatten it to obtain a roughly accurate non-curved picture. I have already done the math necessary to know that given an input pixel at location (x,y)[with 0,0 being the center of the image], where the output pixel (x',y') should be, but I cannot figure out how to apply this to build my new image. I am also aware that due to the fact that the flattened image is larger than the original image, some pixels on the final image will not have a corresponding input pixel (do they appear black? Transparent?), but I'll deal with that when I get there.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `interpol` routine.  If you have a) an array of input coordinates, b) an array of input values, and c) an array of output coordinates you wish to interpolate to, `interpol` (**not** `interpolate`, which is similar but not the same) will do the magic.  Here is copy-pasted from the IDL docs:

```
Result = INTERPOL( V, X, XOUT [, /LSQUADRATIC] [, /NAN] [, /QUADRATIC] [, /SPLINE] )
```

V would be your input *values*, X your input *coordinates*, and XOUT your output coordinates.  They do not have to be on a regular grid, so nice for the kind of mapping you want.